# How to perform automatic graph range extension in Excel (with a constrain)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, range, extension

I'm having a hard time trying to make a graph's range extend automatically
(in Excel). I have done my research and I found this instructive:

https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/creating_automatically_extended_plot_ranges.html

It uses this formula to be applied while creating a "named range":

`=OFFSET(<'Sheet name'>!<'start cell'>;0;0;COUNTA(<'Sheet name'>!<'Column name'>:<'Column name'strong text>) - 1)`

The above site includes this warning:

> After you perform these steps, when you add data to columns B and C,
>   the chart updates automatically to show the new data (...). 
>   To use this technique for your own data,
>   make sure that the first argument for the `OFFSET` function
>   refers to the first data point,
>   and that the argument for `COUNTA` refers to the entire column of data. 
>   **Also, if the columns used for the data contain any other entries,
>   `COUNTA` will return an incorrect value.**

[Emphasis added.]

The problem is the following:

This formula **needs that the blank cells below the last data line written in the given table are totally blank** (this is, blank... no formula in them whatsoever).

It works great if you manually input data in a blank table. Unfortunately, **I need to gather the data from a secondary table which processes data from the first one** (the one in which I really write down the data).

It looks that as this secondary table *does* contain a formula (even if it is made to show " " when no value is available), this method doesn't work.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious. I'm kind of a newbie, so any help would be great.

Comment: do you have a maximum row that you are applying your formula to?  Is the formula being applied to the max row number 1048576 (Varies by version)